# Where is the folder to load Ruby gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

in ruby code, the require statement, such as

```
require 'rest-client'
```

should load the ruby gems from the ruby load path. However , when searching thru the ruby load path, i do not see any rest-client gem? So how the ruby code knows where the ruby gems are located?

irb(main):001:0> $LOAD_PATH

=> ["/home/abc/.rbenv/rbenv.d/exec/gem-rehash", ......]

Comment: You can use `Gem.find_files("rest_client")` to see the path.

Answer (score 0):

RubyGems monkeypatches `Kernel#require`, so that it will try to find a gem which contains that file in the gem path and then "activates" that gem, which basically means to add that gem's library directory to the load path.

In other words, when you call `require`, you will not call the `require` from the core library, you will instead call the `require` from RubyGems which overwrites the one from the core library. And the `require` from RubyGems knows how to search through gems.

Comment: Isn't rubygems always active in modern rubies? And so we never actually call the core version?

Comment: Most implementations support `--disable-rubygems`.